# Sum of all diffs (lines count) that were ever made in branch, even if some got overriden by later commits, and did't made it to the final revision

Tags: git, github, version-control, command-line-interface

Suppose I made two commits:

1. In first one I added 50 lines to the file, and deleted 20, so the diff between my branch and master is `+50, -20`
2. In second one I removed 30 of those 50 lines, I've added in previous commit, and brought back 5 of those 20, I've deleted in previous commit, so diff between my branch and master is `+20, -15`

The diff in guthub for a branch would show `+20, -15`, but I want something like this:

Sum of all diffs, in this case is `(+50)+(+5), (-20)+(-30) = +55, -50`? (sum of all additions and insertions in all commits)

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "I want something like this". Are you asking for a script that would iterate through each commit from A to B and do the math for you?

Comment: Side note, I'm curious what you would use the metrics for?

Comment: Another side note: I'm not sure what you would do for merge commits.

Comment: Note that Git stores only *snapshots*, so to get the numbers you want, you must compute pairwise diffs: (a,b); (b,c); (c, d); ...; (g, h) and then sum the numbers from each such diff. You will have to write this code yourself.

Comment: @TTT Any solution, that would produce this result is good. I wasn't able to find it in build in functionality, so I guess that script is the only option. 
I don't want to count merge commits, only changes I've made to this branch (I was only one commiting to it).
I worked on feature for a month or so, and 90% of the code was rewritten, bc of review comments or changes in requirements. My collegue says, that codebase I was working in is terrible, bc it took so much time to do the feature, and I want to show him, that it's just the code that was rewritten over and over again.

Comment: @torek I guess you're right, thanks